# About Group Policy: 'Do not allow pinning Store app to the Taskbar'

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, group-policy

Using Windows 10 (*TH2* Update), I need to enable this policy:

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Do not allow pinning Store app to the Taskbar
```

The problem is that I can't do it because I've installed the Home edition which comes without gpedit.

However, when a group policy setting is applied a new registry value is created/modified, then just that value serves to automate the group policy setting via registry, so my question is more a request, I just need to know the name and path of the registry value that is created when applying that policy setting, in form of a Regedit script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the requested registry key location and values. (Credit goes to the wonderful guys at GPSearch: http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#10995)

Registry Key: `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`

Value: `NopinningStoreToTaskbar`

Enabled Value:
decimal: `1`

Disabled Value:
decimal: `0`